# Terraform Subnet details not identified inside module

Tags: amazon-web-services, module, terraform, terraform-template-file

I have Terraform script which will create VPC, load balancers, and ECS.
using the module (folder inside the main application folder ) to create task definitions but it will not allow accessing resources created outside this module such as subnets, security groups.
I would like to know how to access those resources from this module folder tf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access, by instance, the ID of the VPC created from a module called `create_vpc`, you need to export it adding something like this to the module code.

**create_vpc/output.tf:**

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value="${aws_vpc.my_vpc.id}"
}
```

NOTE: obviously you need to create a VPC called `my_vpc` inside the module, normally in a file called `create_vpc/main.tf`, but I think that part you have it under control.

Then, you just need to call the `vpc_id` output from that module with something like:

**site/main.tf:**

```
module "create_vpc" {
  source = "../create_vpc"
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "vpc_internet_gateway" {
  vpc_id = "${module.create_vpc.vpc_id}"
}
```

NOTE: here the VPC Internet Gateway created is only a sample to use the VPC ID

In similar way you can export subnets, security group names and ids, etc. from one module to other.